# Does re-assigning a non-function to be a function with set! create a new frame?

Tags: scope, scheme, variable-assignment

The following code is confusing me:

```
(define (even-or-odd-letrec x)
  ((lambda (internal-even? internal-odd?)
     (set! internal-even? (lambda (n)
                (if (= n 0) 'even
                    (internal-odd? (- n 1)))))
     (set! internal-odd? (lambda (n)
               (if (= n 0) 'odd
                   (internal-even? (- n 1)))))
     (internal-even? x))
   #f #f))
```

As I read it, the environments are as follows:

1. Inside the environment of `even-or-odd-letrec`, `internal-even?` and `internal-odd?` are initially bound to `#f`. Their parent environment is the global environment.
2. `set!` then changes these two values to the obvious `lambda`s, but does not change the environments.
3. Because the environments haven't changed, any calls to `internal-even?` will look in the global environment for `internal-odd?` and find nothing.

So how does this code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the title of your question: no, setting does not create any new frames.

Setting sets the value of a binding in the current environment frame. Whatever the old and new values might be. Function or no, makes no difference.

Again, `set!` does not change values. It changes *bindings'* values. A binding is a pairing of a name and its value. `Set!`ting changes that name's bound value.

Seen as a named pointer, after being re-`set!`, a name points to a new value -- that value which was supplied to `set!` as the second argument.

So contrary to what you say, `set!` does *change* the current environment frame -- it mutates its binding for the given name that is sets.

```
  +---------------+                  +---------------+
  |  n1 ---> v1   |                  |  n1 ---> x    |
  |  n2 ---> v2   |   (set! n1 x)    |  n2 ---> v2   | 
  |---------------|  ------------->  |---------------| 
  |  ..code...    |                  |  ..code...    |
  |_______________|                  |_______________|
```

"Any call to `internal-even?` will" ..... stop! this isn't the right way to look at it.

Any reference to `internal-even?` inside the `lambda`-created frame will be resolved by looking up the value under the name `internal-even?` in that same frame, and all will work out fine.

When you `(set! internal-even? (lambda (...) ... internal-odd? ...))`, it is true that `internal-odd?`'s *value* still isn't what it should be, but that's OK, because its value isn't looked up yet -- because `internal-even?` is not yet run either. When a lambda expression is evaluated (here, as part of the `set!` call), its value is the function which says, *when time comes, when this function runs, **then** look up the value of any name in it as it is needed*.

Answer (score 1):

When applied to two argument values, `(lambda (internal-even? internal-odd?) ...)` creates a new environment with bindings for `internal-even?` and `internal-odd?`.  Anything in that environment which refers to `internal-even?` or `internal-odd?` will refer to the current value of those bindings at the time when the code runs.  `set!` *mutates* this environment by altering the values of the bindings, such that the current values of those bindings are now two procedures which themselves refer to the current values of those bindings.

---

By far the easiest way to understand this, I think, is to implement a little interpreter.  It is extremely easy to do this: you use alists for environments, the evaluator needs pretty much to handle `if` and `lambda` and `set!` as special cases.  Everyone should write one of these.

Comment: I think my point of confusion is that `set!` must evaluate its second argument and evaluating that second argument is going to cause nonsense. For example, re-binding (and therefore evaluating) `internal-even?` when `internal-odd?` is still set to `#f` isn't going to give you what you want.

Comment: @J.Mini **finally** you explicate your confusion!.... :) I've edited my answer with the explanation.

Comment: @J.Mini: as Will Ness said, evaluating a form like `(lambda (...) ...)` does *not* look up the values of variables in body of the function: it may check that those variables *exist* (or will exist, in the case of variables bound by the function itself) and complain if they don't (Racket does this, for instance), but they are not looked up until the function is called, and the values which are retrieved are the values which exist at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a variable does not bind a new location.  Note, however, that binding a new variable does not mean to create/enlarge a frame.  It is possible (like in C) to keep variables into registers, not in frames, or not keeping them at all if you can prove things about a variable's behavior.